# Calling Oracle & MySQL Stored Procedures from Virtual Stored Procedure

Tags: teiid

All, 
I am new to TeiiD. I have Oracle and MySQL stored procedures (inserting records into tables) executing successfully from TeiiD VDB as separate procedures using call commands.  I am using SquIrrel tool to execute them independently from Active VDB.

Now, is it possible using Teiid CREATE VIRTUAL PROCEDURE to call both procedures in one go? Something like..

```
CREATE VIRTUAL PROCEDURE myProc () RETURN ()
BEGIN 
Call MyOracleProc();
Call MySQLProc();

END
```

I am not getting any example or syntax to handle this requirement.  I am also trying to use Eclipse Teiid designer plugin for same.

Appreciate help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting any example or syntax to handle this requirement

Yes, you can call source stored procedures just like any other statement in a Teiid virtual procedure using the CALL or EXEC keyword: CALL proc()

See more under http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/13.1.x/content/reference/DML_Commands.html and http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/13.0.x/content/reference/Procedure_Language.html#_command_statement